# Looking to get new pedals for my bike?

Tags: pedals, pedals-flat

I'm looking to purchase some quality flat pedals for my bike. I've been riding cheap plastic ones and they keep breaking! I am currently looking at the Race Face Aeffect since they are aluminum. Any and all recommendations are appreciated!

Comment: We don't really do specific product rec or comparisons.  Try to make your question a bit more about the features to compare, which makes it more long-term useful to future readers.

Comment: I've seen plastic pedals last for decades.

Answer (score 3):

You'll have some things to measure, and some decisions to make.

First, you need to know what the threads on your cranks are.  There's a 99% chance they are 9/16" with a tiny chance of 1/2" thread.  You need to match whatever interface your cranks have.

You're committed to flat pedals, which does limit things a lot.  Don't rule out clipless pedals, or even combo pedals which offer a flat side and a cleat side.

Even in the flat world, there's also a choice between flat and dished (ie your foot has a little shallow bowl to sit in)  And you can choose the surface too, from plastic to rubber, to metal.  Most forms have a flat and a pinnned or studded interface too, which can be good or bad depending on your needs.

---

I suggest you pick a budget amount, and go into your LBS and look at what's on offer.

Answer (score -1):

What are you after? Strength or lightweight?

I have these and they're both.  I weigh 105 kg (232 pounds) and have not bent them at all. Probably recommend the titanium axles if you can stretch.

https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32897043189.html

Comment: Better  to focus on reasons why an item fits OP's requirements.  This particular item will likely only be available for a short time, so to make the answer more useful in the future, its better to say why they suit.   Also editing link to remove your tracking IDs.